# Oracle Eloqua web form pre populating on external server

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I want to pre populate a web form which is created in oracle eloqua. I created this form in eloqua and copied the source code in my sublime editor. I added all the necessary tracking scripts in the code. I hosted this form in oracle eloqua and on a external hosting server.
When I send an email to someone with both urls 1. The eloqua hosted url 2. The externally hosted url.
Point 1 url pre-populates the form with users information.
But this is not happening for point 2. I want to pre populate it using cookies or anything.
Any help will be appreciated. Thank You.